# Why isn't doctype self-closing

Tags: xhtml, doctype

Provided an xhtml doctype like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`, why is this tag itself allowed to be non self-closing / non closing at all?

**Aka** why isn't it: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a tag (element). It's a declaration and that is the syntax for a declaration ([doctype declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) specifically).

Other declarations (`ELEMENT`, `ENTITY`, `ATTLIST`, etc.) have a similar syntax. The `>` closes the declaration.