# HTML not showing up in document?

Tags: html, notepad++

I have all the tags and everything and yet nothing is showing up. Not even the heading. I am using notepad++ for this and I have used it for HTML with no problems(though that is mostly copying HTML from an online code editor).

Does it have to do with the last closing tag? I don't think so since I have added this closing tag to online editors with no difference at all.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Kepler Bb</h1>
<p>This is a planet in</p>
</body>
</html>
</!DOCTYPE>
```

For some reason, when I use notepad++ I get an HTML error(encoding not declared error) but when I use an online editor, I have no problems at all. Why?

Comment: Remove </!DOCTYPE>

Comment: Why? With a code editor I have no problem regardless of whether I have that particular closing tag or not. Plus with the notepad++, since I set the preferences to "autocomplete html tags" it gave me that particular closing tag.

Comment: This is not valid html. Doctype doesn't need to be closed, it's a declaration of what sort of document it is.

Answer (score 2):

The doctype should not be closed. It's a declaration. See this question on SO: [Why isn't doctype self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199106/why-isnt-doctype-self-closing) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
</!DOCTYPE>
```

Add the character encoding in the head: (for example)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```